# Declaring dynamic variable in R

Tags: r

I created a function in R looks like this

```
calcBMI <- function (w,f,i,bmi,h) {

  w <- 204

  f <- 6

  i <- 1

  h <- f * 12 + I

  bmi <- (w / (h * h)) * 703

  return(bmi)

}

#Call Function
calcBMI()
```

everything runs fine

my question is how to call this function with new value w or new f

Evrytime I did

```
w <- 254

calcBMI()
```

I got the old value

Thanks,
Oded Dror

Answer (score 4):

You keep getting the old value because every time you call `calcBMI` the bit of code inside it

```
w <- 204
f <- 6
# ... etc
```

is re-executed, so your BMI calculation uses these values.

What you should do is set anything you want to change the value of, as a parameter in your function, and then *pass those values in*.

i.e.:

```
calcBMI <- function (w, f, i) {
  h <- f * 12 + i # <-- note: in your original post this was 'I' which is not defined?    
  bmi <- (w / (h * h)) * 703   
  return(bmi)    
}
```

Then you *call* `calcBMI` with the values of `w`, `f` and `i` you want:

```
calcBMI(w=204, f=6, i=1) ## 26.91162
calcBMI(w=254, f=6, i=1) ## 33.5076
# and so on ...
```

This way the BMI calculation takes the value of `w`, `f`, and `i` from the parameter values.

(You had `bmi` and `h` as input parameters originally; I removed them because they are calculated from `w`, `f` and `i`, not specified by the user as an input to the BMI calculation).

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend:

```
calcBMI <- function (w=204,f=6,i=1) {
  h <- f * 12 + i  ## note R is case sensitive: i != I
  w / h^2 * 703    ## value of last expression gets returned
}
```

Then:

```
calcBMI()  ## use default values
calcBMI(w=254)
```

Is this homework?

Comment: Sorry for the delay but Thank you, No is not my homework it just for fun learning R